# File name not matching with files inside the folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob, python-os

Greetings I Have Folder named '10k' which contains images named `1_left` `1_right` as shown below.

[image]

My python code to print names of file in Folder:

```
main_file = '10k'
path = os.path.join(main_file,'*g')
files = glob.glob(path)


#l='10k\10_left.jpeg'
for f1 in files:
    #print(os.path.basename(f1))
    fstr=str(f1)
    print(fstr)
```

The output is weird when I Print 
it does not the desired names 
Output :
[image]

Please guide me.

Comment: Insufficient data. You need to tell us what output you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

✓ **@vidit02100**, the problem is really very interesting. As I understood from your code, you want to only print the name of image files present inside **10k** directory.

> In image, you have not commented the lines which you have commented in the problem's code.
>
> If you will show full code and tell about the number of images inside **10k** directory then it would be much better for me to help you.
>
> May be your code will be printing the images in reverse order if there will be +10000 images inside **10k**. Please check and let me know.

✓ As I know, **jpg**, **jpeg** & **png** are the most popular image file extensions that ends with **g**.

✓ So place all these extensions in one list and use another for loop to iterate over it and place your code inside it.

> Please comment if my suggestion doesn't satisfy your need. I will update my answer based on your provided inputs and outputs.

✓ Here is your modified code.

```
main_file = '10k'
file_formats = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg"]

for file_format in file_formats:
    path = os.path.join(main_file, '*.' + file_format )
    files = glob.glob(path)

    for f1 in files:
        fstr = str(f1)
        print(fstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I can only guess what you wanted this to print.

If your desired output is first 1_left then 1_right and so on like it is presented in your folder, the reason for that is that python sorts the files in a different way than you OS does.

As far as I can tell, `files` is just a list. So you could sort it yourself using `sort` and a custom key, like `files.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[0]))`.
This will sort the list by the number at the beginning, and numbers other than strings are sorted like you'd probably expect (so first 1, then 2 and so on).